# Istio 1.6 AuthorizationPolicy does not have proper response code if coming from cross origin

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We have implemented this security filter to pre-validate our JWT token before it reaches the backend services. It is helpful that it can checks some condition that will be your criteria to accept or reject a request.

Our problem now is when you send your request to a different URL (which we already configured the CORS policy in `VirtualService`), the policy rejected the request and doesn't return with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header where it triggers the CORS blocking in Chrome browser.

Here's some example definitions:

Custom Ingress Gateway's policy

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: custom-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      gateway-name: custom-ingress
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: https://some-issuer.com/
    jwksUri: https://some-issuer.com/.well-known/jwks.json
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: custom-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      gateway-name: custom-ingress
  action: DENY
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
    to: 
    - operation:
        methods: ["POST"]
        paths:
        - /restricted/path/A
        - /restricted/path/B
        - /restricted/path/C
```

Service Virtual Service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  hosts:
    - some-host.com
  gateways:
    - istio-system/custom-gateway
  http:
    - name: my-service-route
      match:
        - uri:
            exact: /restricted/path/A
      rewrite:
        uri: /A
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service
            subset: stable
            port:
              number: 8080
      corsPolicy:
        allowOrigins:
        - prefix: https://some-origin.com
        allowMethods:
        - OPTIONS
        - POST
        - GET
        - PUT
        - PATCH
        - DELETE
        allowCredentials: false
        allowHeaders:
        - authorization
        - content-type
        - accept
        - origin
        - grpc-timeout
        - keep-alive
        - user-agent
        - cache-control
        - content-transfer-encoding
        - x-accept-content-transfer-encoding
        - x-accept-response-streaming
        - x-user-agent
        - x-grpc-web
        maxAge: "1h"
```

When Chrome browser request for:

1. OPTIONS /restricted/path/A - returns 200 along with headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
2. POST /restricted/path/A - returns 403 with no other headers

What do you think I should do?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't this working as you configured? You deny POST method in your authorization policy, so options,get,put,patch and delete should work when post will get 403 from auth policy? I assume it should work if you delete `methods: ["POST"]` from your auth policy and leave only the paths.