# Preflight (OPTIONS) returns 403, CORS

Tags: kubernetes, cors, http-status-code-403, istio

We are using Kubernetes with Istio and have configured a virtual service:

```
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api
    rewrite:
      uri: /api
    route:
    - destination:
        host: svc-api
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: stable
      weight: 0
    - destination:
        host: svc-api
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: vnext
      weight: 100
    corsPolicy: &apiCorsPolicy
      allowOrigins:
      - exact: '*'
      allowMethods:
      - GET
      - POST
      - OPTIONS
      allowCredentials: true
      allowHeaders:
      - "*"
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: svc-api
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: stable
      weight: 0
    - destination:
        host: svc-api
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: vnext
      weight: 100
    corsPolicy: *apiCorsPolicy
```

Making a request to `https://[host]/api/*` from a browser fails on OPTIONS request with `'from origin [request] has been blocked by CORS policy'`.

Describing the service in k8 shows the correct configurations.

According to v 1.6.4 the structure using `allowOrigins` and `exact` instead of `allowOrigin` is correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have some type of authorization in your cluster, like jwt? Could you try to change `exact: '*'` to `exact : 'example.com'` and check if the problem still exist? Additionally take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24145), maybe you should add the AllowHeaders instead of using `'*'`.

Comment: @jt97 - thank you for your comment. I did try using a specifc host like `example.com` and I also tried adding in the needed headers instead of using wildcard but with same effect.
We do have a jwt authorization and that is being handled perfectly if the request comes from a server but any browser (that creates an OPTIONS request) fails.

Comment: @jt97 The link you posted only mentions using `allowOrigins` and `exact` instead of just `allowOrigin` - I tried both setups with same results unfortunately.

Comment: Seems like the cors configuration is fine, I asked about the authorization as 403 is the authorization code, and cors didn't work when jwt policy targets the Istio Ingress gateway, there is a [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16171) about that, could you add your request and authorization policies?

Comment: Additionally take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313148/istio-1-6-authorizationpolicy-does-not-have-proper-response-code-if-coming-from), community member have a working options here, but post return 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things worth to mention here.

---

Recently in older istio versions there were a problem with cors and jwt combined together, take a look at below links:

- [Istio 1.5 cors not working - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152587/istio-1-5-cors-not-working-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-c)
- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16171

---

There is another [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23757) about that, in this [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23757#issuecomment-634144575) community member have the same issue, maybe it's worth to open a new github issue for that?

---

Additionally there is an answer from istio dev @howardjohn

> Hi everyone. Testing CORS using curl can be a bit misleading. CORS is not enforced at the server side; it will not return a 4xx error for example. Instead, headers are returned back which are used by browsers to deny/accept. https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/cors.html?highlight=cors gives a good demo of this, and [https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/12/21/web-security-cors/#:~:text=CORS%20isn't%20actually%20enforced,header%20in%20all%20its%20responses](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/12/21/web-security-cors/#:%7E:text=CORS%20isn%27t%20actually%20enforced,header%20in%20all%20its%20responses). is a good explanation.
>
> So Istio's job here is simply to return these headers. I have added a test showing this works: [#26231](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/26231).

---

As I mentioned in comment worth to take a look at another community member configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313148/istio-1-6-authorizationpolicy-does-not-have-proper-response-code-if-coming-from), as he has a working options example, but have a 403 issue with POST.

---

Few things I would change in your virtual service

Use just `corsPolicy` instead of `corsPolicy: &apiCorsPolicy`

```
corsPolicy:
```

Instead of exact you can also use regex which may do the trick for wildcards.

```
allowOrigins:
- regex: '*'
```

About the `/` and `/api` paths, I think prefix is enough here, you don't need rewrite.

---

Comment: Using regex for the wildcard did the trick for me. Thank you